# background-image cropping according to parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with margin left and right and another div with a background-image but no margin.

I have background-size as cover, but the displayed image's right and left portions are cut off but still respects the margins.

The orange is the background-image div and has the numbers 1 through 6, but the grey margin portions cover the image and blocks the 1 and 6, but I'd like to aspect fill the image into the orange portion, respecting the grey margins and fitting all 1 through 6 in the orange portion.

[image]

```
<div style="margin-left: 10vw; margin-right: 10vw;">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>

.image {
    background-image: url("orange.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Edit: New image uploaded

Comment: Can you please add your HTML and CSS as well - So we can help properly. Images does not really help. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a short snippet reproducing this problem?

Comment: As well as the HTML as @AlwaysHelping says, we also need to see the relevant CSS please!

Comment: @FluffyKitten Good reminder :)

Comment: Well your css for `background-image` is incorrect - you have included all the properties as part of `background-image`. Not sure if that's the problem you are seeing, but you'll need to fix that to see what else might be happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, buddy. the answer is really simple.

Make the `div` that contains the class `image` as a parent. Such as this and the image will go full width from left to right.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/108");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div style="margin-left: 10vw; margin-right: 10vw;">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

or just keep it as it is and remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right`

Another option is to do the following.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.image {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="myContent" style="margin-left: 10vw; margin-right: 10vw;">
      <h1>Hi</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this does not answer your question do please leave me a comment and I will do my best to edit the answer to fit your requirements and help you out as much as possible.

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep the grey margins, and just make sure the image fits inside the orange area, instead of removing the grey margins and making the orange area full width.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I want the image to be aspect-filled into the orange portion and display all 1 to 6.

Comment: MM, if you can provide an image of what you are trying to do it could be a great help because the image you showed us is telling us where you are stuck. can you show us a screenshot of the desired output? Also, more CSS and HTML will be appreciated.

Comment: So... you want the image width to exactly fill the orange area width, right? And for the image to be no wider than the orange area?

Comment: I have been reading the question over and over. The image in my solution is actually covering the area from 1 to 6. and the content inside of it respects the margin on the left and right and they don't go all the way to the left or to the right. That's the answer you are looking for. If not do please provide us more HTML and CSS and give us a screenshot of the desired output it makes it easier to help you. @Latcie

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `cover` to `contain`.

Your code will become:

```
<div style="margin-left: 10vw; margin-right: 10vw;">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>

.image {
    background-image: url("orange.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The aspect ratio of your viewing window was causing the height of the image to stretch tall enough to fill the orange box height, and maintaining aspect ratio pushed the sides of the image out of the orange area and into the grey area.

If you made your window less tall it would look like you want, but you don't want to depend on viewer's window aspect ratio.

Instead, using "contain" will limit the image size so that the image fits in the orange area.

Comment: Contain didn't solve the issue, and this has the additional problem of looking really weird if the window gets really wide.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect that. If `contain` restricted the entire width of the image to within the width of the orange area, respecting the grey margins instead of replacing them, then I'd suggest your original question is solved and you have a new question. (If not, please advise exactly what result `contain` produced). Without knowing more about the intended look of the page, the answer could lie in responsive CSS styling and whether the same image is used for different viewport widths or aspect ratios. Feel free to post a new question.

Comment: What I don't understand is the parent div has left and right margins set, but the image div's image ignores that but the actual div respects it. Why does the image div not fit the image width to the div itself?

Comment: I expected it to be due to the word `cover`. Did replacing it with `contain` limit the width of the image to the width of the orange area? If not, what effect did `contain` have?

Comment: Contain still had the image to be the width of the whole span. The difference was that if the window was sized to be larger than the size of the image, it did not expand the image proportionally.

Comment: Ok, in that case your image is too small and I would advocate generating a larger one (or resizing if you must) rather than letting the browser re-render your image larger than 100% of the image file.